# What kind of ceiling fan control type do I need?

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I'd like to buy a new ceiling fan to replace an existing one. The one I have has one switch that controls the light and dimmer, and another on the other side of the room that controls the fan and fan speed. I'd rather not get a remote control. Do I need the fan with a 2-wire control or a 3-wire control to be able to use it like I use the existing one? And if I need a remote to do this, should I get the 2- or 3-wire? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If the fan doesn't come with a remote, it will have three wires to connect.  A neutral, a hot for the light kit, and a hot for the fan.  Any fan without a remote should be a direct replacement for your existing fan.

The new ceiling fan might require a new light dimmer if you plan on using LED bulbs or it requires energy saving bulbs.  As far as I know, fan control switches have remained the same so yours will most likely work.

One thing to check on... Sometimes people install small light ceiling fans on boxes that are not rated for a fan, and it can work for a long time (never do this).  Just make sure that when you remove the old fan (labeling the wires) that you have a metal, fan rated ceiling box.

Comment: Thank you! What is confusing is that I have the option of Fan & Light - 2 Wire, Fan & Light - 3 wire, Handheld Remote, and Wall/Remote Combo. It seems like I want one of the first two options but I don't know which to purchase.

Comment: Do you have a listing for a "2 wire" ?  What you would want is 3 wires.  I don't think I've ever seen one with only two, but I guess if they can save a nickel on the thrid wire...

Comment: Yes-- the listings are:

Fan & Light - 2 Wire: For operation of a fan with a light. Uses only one circuit (two wires). Provides 3 speeds for dimming or on/off light function. Includes wall switch, switch plate and RF receiver.

Fan & Light - 3 Wire: For operation of a fan with light. Requires two circuits (three wires) Provides four fan speeds and dimming function for light.

Am I correct that I should get the 3 wire so I can use my existing separate switch locations?

https://modernfan.com/fan/ball/#controls

Comment: Wait, are you replacing the fan or the switches for the fan?  The old switches will most likely work with a new fan other than the LED compatibility I mentioned.

Comment: I'm just replacing the fan at the ceiling, and leaving the switches as they are. It looks like the "Fan & Light - 3 Wire" is the one that I want?

Comment: I think maybe the confusion is that you are looking at the different controls available for the fan.  That "Ball" model of fan will _always_ come with three wires.  Some houses only have two electrical wires in the ceiling, and some have three.  If you only have two wires in the ceiling, you need one of the "two wire controls".  Since you have two separate switches, you have three wires, but that doesn't change anything about the fan.

Comment: So buy the fan with 3 wire control?

Comment: @SteveJ, yep.  3 wire will give separate control for light and fan.